# Does sizeof(float) always equal to sizeof(int) on all architectures?

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, sizeof

I'm seeing code allocating memory for float using `sizeof(int)`.
I'm wondering whether `sizeof(float)` always equal to `sizeof(int)` on all architectures?

```
float *pointer2Float = (float *) USER_DEFINED_MALLOC (...,..., sizeof(int))
```

Note: this `USER_DEFINED_MALLOC` isa wrapper for conventional malloc, I think.

Thanks

Regards

Comment: You shouldn't even have to care. If you allocate a float, use the size of a float. Besides, `sizeof(*ptr)` should be used instead of `sizeof(int)` anyway.

Comment: No - there are 64 bit platforms which are `ILP64`, where int is 8 bytes but float is still 4 bytes. There are also 16 bit platforms where int is 2 bytes and float is still 4 bytes.

Comment: Also remember that data types are not bound to an architecture. They're defined by an arbitrary data model, and technically, anyone can come up with a new one for any CPU architecture. The most common data models on 64 bit platforms put `long` at 64 bits and `int` at 32 bits, but that's just because it's convenient, not because of some technical restriction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there are implementations (mainly embedded systems) with 16-bit `int` and 32-bit `float`.

And of course, the sizes are allowed to be quite different per the standard.

Comment: would this statement be correct if the architecture is limited to 64bit Intel Nehalem/Sandy_bridge and AMD Opteron

Comment: @elgnoh, I would believe that for most common ABIs on these platforms, it's true that `sizeof(int)==sizeof(float)`, but it would not be theoretically impossible to have a specific system for which it's not the case (for instance, `int` could easily be 64 bits).

Comment: If you place a bet that all implementations on those architectures have 32-bit `int` and 32-bit `float`, I think the risk of you losing the bet is extremely small. But there's no guarantee, someone could make an implementation with 64-bit `int` and 32-bit `float` there just because.

Comment: And it is worth to remember that sizeof() return the size of a type in chars, not bytes. In many embedded processors especially dsp char is two bytes.

Comment: @nyholku As far as the standard is concerned, a byte is _defined_ as the size of a `char`. That could be 8 bits or 16 (or, for that matter, 9; `CHAR_BIT` tells you), it need not be an octet. (Common parlance has most people mean an octet of bits when saying byte, so there's room for misunderstanding and the occasional catastrophe.)

Comment: @DanielFischer you are probably right as fas the standard is concerned, have not read it in years. That is not a very helpful definition. In the old days I think the standard talked about chars and sizeof in terms of chars, which was marginally better because it at least made distinction from the common parlance (which IMO defines the meaning of words as opposed to some official busybody committee). I would bet that if we were to ask 100 programmers "quick, how many bits in a byte" the answer would be eight close to hundred times.

Answer (score 7):

The sizes of ALL types (except `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`<sup>1</sup>) are implementation-defined. So it is **not** guaranteed that `sizeof(float)` will be equal to `sizeof(int)` on *all* platforms.

<sup>1. The size of `char` and all its variants is defined to be 1-byte by the Standard. However, the *number* of bits in 1-byte is implementation-defined!</sup>

Answer (score 4):

No, `sizeof (int)` and `sizeof (float)` values are implementation-defined and are not guaranteed to be the same.

Here is an example of system where the two values are different:

On Cray MPP systems:

```
sizeof (int)  is 8

sizeof (float) is 4
```

See here:

> "Cray C/C++ Reference Manual", Table 3. Cray Research systems data type mapping in "9.1.2.2 Types"

http://docs.cray.com/books/004-2179-003/004-2179-003-manual.pdf

Also most 8-bit embedded systems have an `int` of 16-bit wide with `sizeof (int)` is 2 while floating point follow IEEE-754 and `float` are 32-bit with `sizeof (float)` of 4.

Answer (score 3):

No.  In C and C++, data types are platform specific.  In general, this will mean:

> But for other systems, the general specification is that int has the natural size suggested by the system architecture (one "word") and the four integer types char, short, int and long must each one be at least as large as the one preceding it, with char being always one byte in size. The same applies to the floating point types float, double and long double, where each one must provide at least as much precision as the preceding one.

(Taken from [Data Types](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/))

On many platforms, float and int are both often 32bit, but this isn't always the case, nor is it part of the actual specification.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no guarantee that `sizeof (float)` be equal to `sizeof (int)`, and I'd consider the above to be a coding error.

It *should* use `sizeof *ptrToFloat` in favor of either `sizeof (int)` or `sizeof (float)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a multi platform  that size of data type is very important, you can create an header file such as :

```
#define INT sizeof(int)
#define FLOAT sizeof(float)
.
.
.
```

It's a trick to cheat arch.