# What does this union in Intel's Embree do?

Tags: c++, intel, intrinsics

This is from vec3fa.h in Intel's [Embree code](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/embree-photo-realistic-ray-tracing-kernels).

```
struct __aligned(16) Vec3fa
{
typedef float Scalar;
enum { N = 3 };
union {
  __m128 m128;
  struct { float x,y,z; union { int a; float w; }; };
};

// other stuff in struct

};
```

What is the outer union doing? The inner union is even more mysterious to me.
The a and w variables are never referred to in the code.

It looks like this provides a convenient and clean way of reading and writing to m128, x, y, and z with the appropriate aliases. How does it work?

How did an int get involved??

Comment: I imagine it is for doing SSE instruction on 4 floats at once. It is faster than doing it on 3 floats separately. 4th dimension is redundant in 3D vector, but `__m128` is 4 floats, so they pad it with a dummy (why they use inner union for `int` and `float`, and not just 4th `float` - not apparent to me). Outer union is to be able to use either `__m128` or access as independent vector components.

Comment: That much is clear, but why is there an int? Also, how can you know that the union between __m128 and the struct give you the intended mapping?

Comment: Because `sizeof(__m128)` = 128 bit = 16 bytes = 4 floats. `int` and `float` are both 4 bytes, so they can use either. Question why do they need `int` at all - I don't know.

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833105/does-sizeoffloat-always-equal-to-sizeofint-on-all-architectures, sizeof(int) is not necessarily equal to sizeof(float) but it very likely is. Maybe the int is there just to make things more interesting on rare occasions?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - not necessarily, but on most systems it is. Why using `int` at all - you have the source code ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are [anonymous](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) [unions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35ect93t.aspx) (and a struct). What they do is define anonymous instance of the struct or union inplace and are used to avoid clutter when accessing members. The above code is layout compatible to this one:

```
struct __aligned(16) Vec3fa
{
  typedef float Scalar;
  enum { N = 3 };
  union {
    __m128 m128;
    struct { float x,y,z; union { int a; float w; } u2; } s;
  } u1;
  // other stuff in struct
};
```

But now member access is more complicated:

```
Vec3fa v;      // offset from struct start ((char*)&member - (char*)&v):
v.u1.m128;     // 0
v.u1.s.x;      // 0
v.u1.s.y;      // 4
v.u1.s.z;      // 8
v.u1.s.u2.w;  // 12
v.u1.s.u2.a;  // 12
```

Instead of the library variant:

```
Vec3fa v;      // offset from struct start ((char*)&member - (char*)&v):
v.m128;        // 0
v.x;           // 0
v.y;           // 4
v.z;           // 8
v.w;           // 12
v.a;           // 12
```

Comment: Can you actually refer to v.w and v.a when they're doubly nested and those nests are both anonymous? The names a and w could legally be declared elsewhere without clear priority of one declaration or the other.

Comment: Yes you can. Deep nesting does not change that but because it's no longer possible to distinguish `Vec3fa`'s members from the members of the anonymous `unions` or the `struct`, you must use different names. For example it's not legal to rename `a` to `y`, as `v.y` would become ambiguous and the definition will raise a compiler error.

Comment: Note that while you _can_ access the components, this is a very serious performance killer. It forces storing the XMM register to memory and doing a dependent re-load to a register, which is a full pipeline stall.

Comment: @Damon: It's not good, but it's not *that* bad.  x86 CPUs can forward data from a vector store to an integer reload.  It's not like a PowerPC / Cell load-hit-store stall on any Intel/AMD CPUs.  It has maybe 6 cycle store-forwarding latency, but there's no stall.  Also, smart compilers will compile to shuffle instructions that extract an FP element into the bottom of an XMM register (i.e. a scalar float) instead of store/reload.  Or for an `int` member, maybe an SSE4 `pextrd` ALU instruction that extracts directly from XMM to integer.

Answer (score 2):

> How did an int get involved??

Intels Embree is a ray tracing kernel library. In computer graphics, you could imagine the need for sometimes using a 4-element vector for color and alpha, or for representing position using homogeneous coordinates.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates